# Is the gravatar resized proportionally to the submitted text length in the chat room?

Tags: support, chat, avatar

Is the gravatar resized proportionally to the submitted text length in the chat room?

[image: Example of gravatar in different sizes in chat]

Comment: It certainly changes size, but within what look like pre-sets.

Comment: I’m a little bit sad, that you changed your avatar. The finger art was nice! (Well, the garbage man is funny, too …) And a list of your older names would be nice. ;-)

Comment: @Speravir: I am sorry. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite proportionally, but it does indeed depend on how many lines the message(s) use and thus how much space is available for the user's "signature" on the left. See [this answer of mine on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145625/115866) for some more information.